How do I relate crying to SOMETHING else that could instantly be understood as crying/tears?
This is just for my journal, but oftentimes I get stuck trying to find cool and unique ways of describing things/ situations. In this instance, I was in a heated argument with my parents yesterday, with me crying, etc. I don’t want to simply state the exact events word for word as I write. What are some things in life that you could instantly relate to crying/ difficult emotions? ( because it’s with water( tears- wet) most solutions i’ve thought of sound… well strange. This is the best example I have so far, “Parents and I had a draining, tissue-wiping-eyes convo last night…”. Idk:/

There's nothing wrong with writing "crying" every time. This is your journal, not an essay or a novel. But there are plenty of other words, like sobbing, howling, sniffling, weeping, and so on, each with different connotations for how loudly and strongly you cry. There are other aspects you could touch on, like having to blow your nose, or how many tissues you went through. Did you get red in the face angry? Were you scared? Did you feel tricked? Betrayed? Embarrassed? Jealous? What emotions led to the tears?
"tissue-wiping-eyes" contains none of that. No matter how much you cry, how strongly and for how long, or the reason, you will eventually need to wipe your eyes with a tissue. Even allergies will do that! Either get wilder and more graphic about precisely what your body is doing or focus on the thoughts and feelings that are leading to those tears.
